# Setting transparency background a view in xml

Tags: android, xml, background-color

I have seen an issue that I do not understand. Please help me out

I have set a transparent background to a `button` in one `activity` and in another `activity` i set transparent `background` in the `editText` using `xml`

android:background="@color/transparent "

where transparent = #00000000

When i call the `activity` android sometime takes an image from my `drawable` and place it there instead of the transparent color. When i kill the `activity` and again call that `activity` , this issues is not seen.

Does any one know why this happens? Please help.

Comment: try to set android:background="#00000000"

Comment: Do you use eclipse for development? If so try to clean you project before deploying it to the device after you have changed values in the res folders. Some times the eclipse don't recognized changed values and uses old once.

Comment: try to clean and build the project. check once again. pls post the code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

try to this  android:background="@android:color/transparent"